# What's the difference between "ertragen", "erdulden" and "aushalten"?

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english

What's the difference between *ertragen* and *erdulden* and *aushalten* and I would like to know what's the most used word in real life.

Comment: We don't see, what you already have investigated and whether at all. My second objection is, what the restriction to real life is meant for. You want us to exclude fictional literature? For authors and bookshops, that's real life, too. :)

Answer (score 4):

Those verbs are almost synonymous in meaning. *Aushalten* is the most colloquial of those:

> Hälst du es noch ein wenig länger aus?
>
> Geht's noch!? Der Lärm ist ja nicht zum Aushalten!

The verb *ertragen* is used in a higher register of speech, for example in formal descriptions, and literature.

> Er konnte die Schmerzen kaum ertragen.
>
> Diese Vorstellung ertrug sie nicht.

Note that both verbs are almost exclusively used in a negative context.

There's also an adjective *erträglich* made from *ertragen*. It's used in colloquial speech as well.

> In diesem Club war es unerträglich laut, deshalb sind wir früh gegangen.
>
> Die Preise waren gerade noch erträglich, daran lag es nicht.

The verb *erdulden* is very high-brow and in difference to the previous ones, also used in seemingly positive contexts. Don't use that verb. In most cases, a plain *dulden* or even *erlauben* does the trick.

> Er hatte viel zu erdulden.
>
> Sie haben die Überquerung ihres Grundstücks zu (er)dulden, da ein Wegerecht besteht.

Comment: a) Du lieferst keine Begründung, wieso er "erdulden" nicht nutzen soll. Kannst Du sie nachliefern? b) Wenn jmd. die Grundstücksüberquerung zu erdulden hat, dann kann er sie gar nicht erlauben, denn man kann nichts erlauben, was man nicht verbieten kann. Du kannst auch niemandem den Gebrauch von bestimmten Verben erlauben oder verbieten.

Comment: Weil *erdulden* sehr abgehobene Sprache ist. Das habe ich auch geschrieben.

Comment: Da stellt sich aber erstens die Frage, wie Du wissen kannst, dass Deine Leser nicht mal abgehobene Sprache nutzen wollen, die so abgehoben zweitens gar nicht ist, und drittens, beispielsweise, wie Dein Beispiel aufzeigt, schlicht juristische Fachsprache sein kann. Viertens nutzen wir Sprache sehr oft um nicht uns selbst, sondern Dritten Ausdruck zu verleihen. Man kann also gerade um Abgehobenheit auszudrücken *erdulden* verwenden. In Kreisen, die den Terminus selbst fleißig im aktiven Wortschatz führen, freilich kaum. Insgesamt, ein non sequitor.